# ASP MVC - Cast ViewModel Object to another type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel like this :

```
public class Column {

    public string Name;

    public string Type;

    public object Content;

}
```

**Content** can be an *int*, *string*... Depending on the **Type** I call the specific EditorTemplate : *Column_int*, *Column_string*... no problem.
I do however have a type **GeoPoint** I want to use too, with the corresponding EditorTemplate *Column_GeoPoint*. The problem is that in my controller, when the ViewModel gets posted, when I do :

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = ((GeoPoint) mViewModel.Content);
```

I get a cast exception.
Any ideas on how to incorporate an object inside another one in the ViewModel ?

Comment: you can use generics instead of using object

Comment: don't you want just make 2 Editor templates? 1 for int variant and 1 for string.

Comment: i mean 2 models and 2 editor templates.

Comment: @teovankot why not ? that seems exactly as something you Would want to do.

Comment: When you debug your code, what is inside Content before it fails at the cast?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive proper data in format you expect, you need to provide custom cast method/helper/extension.

See here how to write custom explicit cast: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The default model binder will not be able to convert an object to `GeoPoint` via `cast`.  I've not used `GeoPoint` before, but a quick google doesn't show how this can be easily converted from a string, perhaps that's not relevant if your Editor handles it correctly

You'll need to convert it correctly/manually (via code).

Your best option is to *always* use the **correct strong types** in your *viewmodel*, ie:

```
public class ColumnViewModel {
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public string ContentString;
    public int ContentInt;
    public GeoPoint ContentGeoPoint;
}
```

ie do not use a weakly-typed, vague "object" property to handle different scenarios.

Then map that to your DTO in the controller:

```
public class Column {
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public object Content;
}

public ActionResult PostAction(ColumnViewModel model)
{
    var dto = new Column();
    switch (model.Type)
    {
        case "int": 
            dto.Content = dto.ContentInt;

        case "geo": 
            dto.Content = dto.ContentGeoPoint;
            break;

       // etc
    }
}
```

It would be better to have multiple view models, so there aren't unused properties (which can be confusing to maintain in the future) - a perfect case for inheritance.  Or use generics for this property as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could always be lazy and add a ToGeoPoint() method in your Column viewmodel.

It would look something like:

```
public class Column {

    public string Name;

    public string Type;

    public object Content;

    public GeoPoint ToGeoPoint() {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint();
        point.Name = this.Name;
        point.Type = this.Type;
        point.Content = this.Content;
        return point;
    }

}
```

Of course this assumes that a GeoPoint and a Column have the same structure. Even if they don't it should be easy to see how to modify this method to allow for that.